# Edit beginning and the end of a big file

Tags: file, sed

I need to edit several files of 500MB or more as follow:

**Original file**:

```
{'key_1': true, 'key_2': 1},
{'key_1': true, 'key_2': 3},
...
{'key_1': false, 'key_2': 50},
```

**Result**:

```
[{'key_1': true, 'key_2': 1},
{'key_1': true, 'key_2': 3},
...
{'key_1': false, 'key_2': 50}]
```

Adding "[" to beginning and changing the last "," for "]".

I want to edit all the *.json files in a folder. Which is the most simple way?

Comment: What do you mean by "best"? Most memory-efficient, most disk-IO-efficient? What solutions have you tried already to solve this and what were your results?

Comment: @Mort you'r right, should be "the most simple way".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sed -i '1 s/^/[/; $ s/,$/]/' *.json
```

That is, on the first line, replace the beginning with `[`, and on the last line, replace the trailing `,` with `]`.